# Convergent sequence that satisfy $y_{n+1}=3y_n^2-3y_n+1$

Tags: limits

Let be the sequence $y_n$ with $0<y_0<1$ such that
$$y_{n+1}=3y_n^2-3y_n+1$$
and
$$0<y_n<1$$
for every $n$ positive integer.
Prove that $y_n$ is convergent with the limit $\frac{1}{3}$.

This is what I dis
$$y_{n+1}-\frac{1}{3}=\left(y_n-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(3y_n-2\right)$$
Therefore
$$y_{n+1}-\frac{1}{3}=\left(y_0-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(3y_n-2\right)\left(3y_{n-1}-2\right)\left(3y_{n-2}-2\right)...\left(3y_0-2\right)$$
then
$$\left|y_{n+1}-\frac{1}{3}\right|=\left|\left(y_0-\frac{1}{3}\right)\right|\left(\left|3y_n-2\right|\right)\left(\left|3y_{n-1}-2\right|\right)...\left(\left|3y_0-2\right|\right)$$
if we denote $$z_n=\left|3y_n-2\right|$$
then
$$0<z_n<1$$
And we have to prove that
$$\lim _{n\to \infty \:\:}\left(z_1z_2...z_n\right)=0$$
and we are done.
I suppose that the right hand side is convergent to $0$, but how should I prove that? Please help!!!

Comment: The question is flawed. If $0<y_0<1$, then $\dfrac{11}{12}<y_1<3$, $y_2>1$ and the next iterates diverge very quickly.

Comment: @pawel: $l=3l^2-l+1$ has no real solution !

Comment: Did you mean $y_{n+1}=3(y_n^2-y_n)+1$?

Comment: Yes Tipping Octopus you are right, I changed it. Thank you

Comment: As this question already has an answer, you might be better rolling back your edits/corrections and reposting it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

$l=\frac{1}{3}$ is surely not a limit of the sequence as the map $f(x)=3x^2-x+1$ is continuous and $l$ is not one of its fixed point.

Comment: Indeed, $f$ has no fixed point !